# DB-Link Oracle 2 PostGIS (Postgresql): Type ST_Geometry or long not working

Tags: postgresql, oracle

We have to query data from a PostGIS (Postgresql) database within Oracle. We established a database link via ODBC Driver (PostgreSQL Unicode (x64) 12.02, PLSQLODBC35W.DLL).

So this is working for usual datatypes like:

```
select "column1", "column2"
from "schema"."tablename"@dblink
```

But we also need to query the geometry column:

```
select "column1", "column2",
       "geometryCol"
from "schema"."tablename"@dblink
```

This leads to ORA-00600. So I tried

```
select "column1", "column2",
       to_lob("geometryCol")
from "schema"."tablename"@dblink
```

This leads to ORA-22992. So I tried to convert it to text first:

```
select "column1", "column2",
       "ST_AsText"@dblink("geometryCol")
from "schema"."tablename"@dblink
```

This leads to ORA-00904: "ST_AsText": invalid ID. So it's somehow not possible to call remote functions, even functions like substring() are not working.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Not sure, but the function is called `st_astext`, not `ST_AsText`, and case matters inside double quotes.

Comment: doesn't matter, not working either

Comment: You may not find a simple solution; oracle gateways impose datatype restrictions on heterogeneous data and it's likely that longs and geometries are too complex to be handled through the gateway. You may have to use functions within views on the source side to convert the information in them to some transportable datatype that is recognized and reassemble in whatever type makes sense for it on the Oracle side using local PL/SQL functions. If at all possible, don't use longs, use LOBs on the target if its >4KB. The geometry may be trickier and may require experience with Spatial functions.